# Paypal MassPayItem Type with USERID

Tags: php, curl, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

I am getting an error with Masspayment while using User ID.

**Command**:

```
curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d
'USER=xxxx`
&PWD=XXX
&SIGNATURE=XXXX
&METHOD=MassPay
&VERSION=93
&RECEIVERTYPE=UserID
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&EMAILSUBJECT= You have a new payment from TEST
&L_ReceiverID0=XXXX
&L_AMT0=1.23
&L_NOTE0=Thank you for our catered lunch.
&L_UNIQUEID0=T111'
```

**Error output:**

> TIMESTAMP=2014%2d08%2d22T13%3a37%3a46Z&CORRELATIONID=a8e6187f731bd&ACK=Failure&VERSION=93&BUILD=12471160&L_ERRORCODE0=10312&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Masspay%20server%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=The%20masspay%20server%20has%20reported%20errors&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Comment: It might not make any difference but I noticed `L_ReceiverID0` is not in all caps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the UserId you are using to send the mass payment to belongs to the live
    environment . You need to make sure that the UserID must belong to the test(sandbox) account not
    the live one . Try to pass the user id from a sandbox account and should be working fine .